# Cloud Run: absent billing account on project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get a simple hello world app running on google run using this tutorial :

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#java

I have to first create a project "hello world", and in my browser it looks like this :

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to build/containerize my app. I do this locally on my computer using the gcloud shell. I assume that is what the tutorial is suggesting.

I go into my helloworld directory and the tutorial says that I should use this command :

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld
```

OK. So **PROJECT-ID** is found by calling this command :

```
gcloud config get-value project
```

My project Id (I think...) is **sboot-project-id**. Based on what I see in my console.

[image]

Then according to what I should do, my next step would be :

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/sboot-project-id/helloworld
```

However if I run this command I get this error :

```
The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account.
```

I have billing activated so this error seems confusing to me.

What is this error trying to tell me?

Have I got project-id wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project id as seen from the screenshot is `helloworld-289513`.

```
gcloud config get-value project
```

gives you the current active project in your environment.

You can do one of two things

1.

```
gcloud config set project helloworld-289513
```

This will set the current project in your environment to the helloworld project

2.

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/sboot-project-id/helloworld --project="helloworld-289513"
```

to run the command against the helloworld project, without changing the environment project.

Comment: If I try setting the project I get: WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [helloworld-289513] or it does not exist..If I perform gcloud projects list. Then it also does not list it

Comment: OK i think i know what the problem was. I had TWO google accounts, and I was getting confused between the two. Both accounts had different projects, and I was trying to access one project through the other account

Comment: It might happen that the current logged in account is different from the one you created a new project.
Try `gcloud auth list` to ensure that you are logged into the right account.
You can use `gcloud auth login` to add another account, or
`gcloud config set account [Account]` to switch accounts.